# How to select the first row of each 'user id' of a column containing a trajectory data using Pandas?

Tags: select, unique

The user ids are already sorted based on the timestamp values. And I need to find only the first row of unique user ids.[Screenshot of the dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVdZI.png)

Comment: If you want a solution using a programming language (Python? Pandas?) you need to mention it in your question, or at least add the pertinent tags. You can't expect people to guess what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know @APC.

Comment: I found the answer to this solution after some more searching on the internet. Apparently, df.drop_duplicates(['userid']) works good for this.

Comment: It is great that you found the solution. Please close the question if it is resolved. Also, it is easy for community to help if the dataframe is in text format and not in image format. [How to ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)